# PHP snippet ruins HTML markup

Tags: php, xhtml

I am trying to implement a php script into a xhtml template. The markup of the template however is a little bit different then the script handles it.

In the template i have menu items and submenu items. A sample code from a static navigation menu looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Men TEES</a></li> <-- is a menu item (note the end </li>)

<li><a href="#">WO Tees</a>  <-- menu item with submenu items
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Desktop PCs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Laptop PCs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TVs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Printers &amp; Ink</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Electronics &amp; Accesories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation</a>
    <ul>
```

The php script has this piece of code to write the menu and submenu items:

```
<?php


        //Get all categories            
    foreach(getCategories($_SESSION['shop']) as $catid=>$cat)

        {
            echo "<li><a href='?categorie=",$catid,"'>",ucfirst(strtolower($cat)),"</a></li>";
        }

        //Get all subcategories in categorie
    foreach(getSubCategories($catid,$_SESSION['shop']) as $subcatid=>$subcat)

        {
            echo "<ul><li><a href='?categorie=",$catid,"&amp;subcategorie=",$subcatid,"'>",ucfirst(strtolower($subcat)),"</a></li>";
        }

?>
```

Can someone help me with this? Cause when there is no subitem it also writes the end `</li>` and if there IS a subitem it doesnt write the `<ul>` after it so the markup messes up.

EDIT: These are the php functions:

```
//Functions to get an array with categories
function getCategories($shopid='')
{
    $output=array();
    if($shopid!='')
    {
        //Get categories for this shop
        $SQL_get_categorie="SELECT * FROM m4n_category WHERE id IN (SELECT catid FROM m4n_shops_cats WHERE shopid='".$shopid."') order by name";
        $SQL_get_categorie_res=mysql_query($SQL_get_categorie);
        while($SQL_get_categorie_data=mysql_fetch_array($SQL_get_categorie_res))
        {
            $id=$SQL_get_categorie_data['id'];
            $output[$id]=$SQL_get_categorie_data['name'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Get all categories
        $SQL_get_categorie="SELECT * FROM m4n_category order by name";
        $SQL_get_categorie_res=mysql_query($SQL_get_categorie);
        while($SQL_get_categorie_data=mysql_fetch_array($SQL_get_categorie_res))
        {
            $id=$SQL_get_categorie_data['id'];
            $output[$id]=$SQL_get_categorie_data['name'];
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

//Functions to get an array with subcategories in a category
function getSubCategories($catid='',$shopid='')
{
    $output=array();
    if($shopid!='')
    {
        //Get subcategories for this shop
        $SQL_get_categorie="SELECT * FROM m4n_subcategory WHERE category_id='".$catid."' AND id IN (SELECT subcatid FROM m4n_shops_cats WHERE shopid='".$shopid."')order by name";
        $SQL_get_categorie_res=mysql_query($SQL_get_categorie);
        while($SQL_get_categorie_data=mysql_fetch_array($SQL_get_categorie_res))
        {
            $id=$SQL_get_categorie_data['id'];
            $output[$id]=$SQL_get_categorie_data['name'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Get all subcategories
        $SQL_get_categorie="SELECT * FROM m4n_subcategory WHERE category_id='".$catid."' order by name";
        $SQL_get_categorie_res=mysql_query($SQL_get_categorie);
        while($SQL_get_categorie_data=mysql_fetch_array($SQL_get_categorie_res))
        {
            $id=$SQL_get_categorie_data['id'];
            $output[$id]=$SQL_get_categorie_data['name'];
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Thanks for the answer, tho if a menu item contains submenu items it doesnt close with a `</li>` but starts directly with `<ul>`

Comment: Can you please give an example input array? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the subcategories within the categories loop, then the `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s can be opened/closed in the correct places.

e.g.

```
<?php
    // Get all categories            
    foreach(getCategories($_SESSION['shop']) as $catid => $cat)
    {
        // Notice no </li> at end!
        echo "<li><a href='?categorie=",$catid,"'>",ucfirst(strtolower($cat)),"</a>";

        // Get all subcategories in category
        $subcats = getSubCategories($catid, $_SESSION['shop']);

        // If there are some sub categories, then start a sub-list.
        if (count($subcats) > 0) 
        { 
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($subcats as $subcatid => $subcat)
            {
                echo "<li><a href='?categorie=",$catid,"&amp;subcategorie=",$subcatid,"'>",ucfirst(strtolower($subcat)),"</a></li>";
            }  
            echo "</ul">;
        }

        // Now you can close the <li> as the sublist is done.   
        echo "</li>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tho if a menu item contains submenu items it doesnt close with a `</li>` but starts directly with `<ul>`

Comment: @user1171942 I've updated my answer so it only outputs the sublist if there are actually items for the sublist.